# How to find solution when 200 user access site and call a store at the same time made SQL Server Azure die

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a store to get a list of something in system. To get information by business requirement, this store selects data from 20 tables in a database and makes some complex calculations.

I tuned this store, it run very fast about 0.4s for a user, max output result is 160 thousand records. But when test with more than 200 user access at the same time made database down, it spend 80%-100% resource of database.

My database is SQL Azure using max allowed resourced from Microsoft (24 vcore, 3k DTU, database size IS around 30G).

If anyone is an expert in this areas, please suggest a solution to solve these issues, my system is a web app allowing users around the world access. My team also is tuning from app as using catching, sharing between app and database.

Comment: How do you expect advice without providing DDL, sample data, and the stored procedure code?

Comment: The [execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) might help too. Assuming the query is purely CPU bound and it takes .4s to run a single query, you won't be able to run more than 9.6 per second with 24 vcores and less if it's a parallel query. Caching is likely at least part of the solution.

Comment: Hi, if my answer helps you, could you please accept it?Thanks and have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [Intelligent Insights to troubleshoot Azure SQL Database performance issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-intelligent-insights-troubleshoot-performance).

Intelligent Insights automatically detects performance issues with SQL Database and Managed Instance databases based on query execution wait times, errors, or time-outs. It outputs detected performance patterns to the diagnostics log.
[image]
[image]

As you said,when test with more than 200 user access at the same time made database down, it spend 80%-100% resource of database. You can follow this tutorial , maybe can help you solve and optimize Azure SQL database performance issue.

Hope this helps.